# Glasses with eye sensors

Tags: sensors, motion

Someone could tell me if there are wearable devices such as glasses, with sensors that can detect eye movement?

In particular, I would need a device like google glass, having a sensor or a camera that is facing the eye, and it can capture the movement, possibly interfaced with a mobile device.

Alternatively, are there micro-cameras on the market, which can be connected via Bluetooth or USB to a mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

These devices are called gaze trackers. There are [open source libraries](http://www.gazegroup.org/forum/) for using webcams and [out of the box solutions](http://www.eyetracking-glasses.com) available. Google has many more options. Cheers!